# Remove last column from txt (pdb file keeping its original formating

Tags: sed

column file separated by the spaces
HEADER NpXynWT_apo_300K_0001_amber

```
ATOM      1  N   MET     1      22.849   2.086  17.904  1.00  0.00           N  
ATOM      2  CA  MET     1      21.710   2.631  17.411  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      3  C   MET     1      20.525   1.737  17.578  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      4  O   MET     1      20.530   0.650  17.113  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      5  CB  MET     1      21.878   2.974  15.929  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      6  CG  MET     1      20.710   3.743  15.334  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      7  SD  MET     1      20.954   4.142  13.593  1.00  0.00           S  
ATOM      8  CE  MET     1      22.272   5.350  13.704  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      9  HA  MET     1      21.472   3.545  17.955  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     10  HB2 MET     1      22.788   3.567  15.838  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     11  HB3 MET     1      22.004   2.033  15.394  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     12  HG2 MET     1      19.813   3.133  15.439  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     13  HG3 MET     1      20.589   4.667  15.900  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     14  HE1 MET     1      23.144   4.895  14.173  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     15  HE2 MET     1      22.536   5.694  12.704  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     16  HE3 MET     1      21.939   6.198  14.303  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     17  H1  MET     1      22.632   1.159  18.243  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     18  H2  MET     1      23.105   2.667  18.689  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM     19  H3  MET     1      23.471   2.005  17.112  1.00  0.00           H
```

from this file I need to remove the last column, keeping the same number of spaces between the rest columns in the output:
HEADER NpXynWT_apo_300K_0001_amber

```
ATOM      1  N   MET     1      22.849   2.086  17.904  1.00  0.00  
ATOM      2  CA  MET     1      21.710   2.631  17.411  1.00  0.00 
ATOM      3  C   MET     1      20.525   1.737  17.578  1.00  0.00 
ATOM      4  O   MET     1      20.530   0.650  17.113  1.00  0.00  
ATOM      5  CB  MET     1      21.878   2.974  15.929  1.00  0.00  
ATOM      6  CG  MET     1      20.710   3.743  15.334  1.00  0.00
ATOM      7  SD  MET     1      20.954   4.142  13.593  1.00  0.00  
ATOM      8  CE  MET     1      22.272   5.350  13.704  1.00  0.00  
ATOM      9  HA  MET     1      21.472   3.545  17.955  1.00  0.00 
ATOM     10  HB2 MET     1      22.788   3.567  15.838  1.00  0.00
ATOM     11  HB3 MET     1      22.004   2.033  15.394  1.00  0.00  
ATOM     12  HG2 MET     1      19.813   3.133  15.439  1.00  0.00
ATOM     13  HG3 MET     1      20.589   4.667  15.900  1.00  0.00
ATOM     14  HE1 MET     1      23.144   4.895  14.173  1.00  0.00
ATOM     15  HE2 MET     1      22.536   5.694  12.704  1.00  0.00  
ATOM     16  HE3 MET     1      21.939   6.198  14.303  1.00  0.00 
ATOM     17  H1  MET     1      22.632   1.159  18.243  1.00  0.00  
ATOM     18  H2  MET     1      23.105   2.667  18.689  1.00  0.00  
ATOM     19  H3  MET     1      23.471   2.005  17.112  1.00  0.00
```

I suppose I need some SED function indicating the type of separator (number of the spaces), the number of the column (the last one). Are there some universal sollution which will remove always the last column with **any number of the preceeding spaces**?

Comment: Even now I'm not sure if the leading spaces are intentionally meant or incorrectly used ;), will leave it to the OP

Answer (score 2):

if the data in `d` file, tried on gnu sed:

```
 sed -E 's/(.*)\s*\S+\s*/\1/' d
```

tried on gnu awk:

```
awk -F' *' '{l=gensub(/(.*)\s\S+\s*$/,"\\1",1);print l}' d
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/ *[^ ]* *$//' file
ATOM      1  N   MET     1      22.849   2.086  17.904  1.00  0.00
ATOM      2  CA  MET     1      21.710   2.631  17.411  1.00  0.00
ATOM      3  C   MET     1      20.525   1.737  17.578  1.00  0.00
ATOM      4  O   MET     1      20.530   0.650  17.113  1.00  0.00
ATOM      5  CB  MET     1      21.878   2.974  15.929  1.00  0.00
ATOM      6  CG  MET     1      20.710   3.743  15.334  1.00  0.00
ATOM      7  SD  MET     1      20.954   4.142  13.593  1.00  0.00
ATOM      8  CE  MET     1      22.272   5.350  13.704  1.00  0.00
ATOM      9  HA  MET     1      21.472   3.545  17.955  1.00  0.00
ATOM     10  HB2 MET     1      22.788   3.567  15.838  1.00  0.00
ATOM     11  HB3 MET     1      22.004   2.033  15.394  1.00  0.00
ATOM     12  HG2 MET     1      19.813   3.133  15.439  1.00  0.00
ATOM     13  HG3 MET     1      20.589   4.667  15.900  1.00  0.00
ATOM     14  HE1 MET     1      23.144   4.895  14.173  1.00  0.00
ATOM     15  HE2 MET     1      22.536   5.694  12.704  1.00  0.00
ATOM     16  HE3 MET     1      21.939   6.198  14.303  1.00  0.00
ATOM     17  H1  MET     1      22.632   1.159  18.243  1.00  0.00
ATOM     18  H2  MET     1      23.105   2.667  18.689  1.00  0.00
ATOM     19  H3  MET     1      23.471   2.005  17.112  1.00  0.00
```

- `*` matches zero or more spaces,
- `[^ ]*` matches zero or more of any characters but space,
- `s/regexp/replacement/` matches `regexp` against input lines and replaces matching substring with `replacement`.

There are trailing spaces in your sample and above command will remove them too. If your actual input doesn't have them, use:

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]*$//' file
```

If those trailing spaces are actually carriage returns (i.e your input has Windows line endings):

```
sed 's/ *[^ ]*\r$//' file
```

Comment: it's a space separated file as it has been indicated in my first post so I need a solution which would be work for any number of spaces in the last column!

Answer (score 1):

This works for gnu sed:

```
 sed -r 's/\s+\S+$//' file
```